# When Mixing two Shaders, how would one have a more organic, wiggly transition, instead of a hard line?

Tags: materials, shaders, shader-nodes

This node setup, disregarding the Vector Curve which I am failing to use, mixes two Shaders together, but with a long enough mesh, a hard line is very obvious. Here it is marked by blue.

How would one break this hard line into something more organic, wiggly, and speckled as indicated by red?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a vector curve, try displacing the whole vector with random noise - it will make it procedural and non repetitive (it will also work with a handpainted texture mask).

For the speckles use Musgrave Texture. You may limit specles placement with a ramp.

Tweak the scales and ramps to make it suit your needs better.

[image: Shader arrangement]

Answer (score 13):

You can distort the gradient with a Noise texture

1. *Noise texture* to control the scale of the noise
2. *Vector Math > Multiply* to control the amount of distortion
3. *Color Ramp* to control the gradient position

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try adding Voronoi texture to the gradient texture of the blend coefficient.

Comment: Voronoi is a common texture in nature, so feel free to use.