# I've got a material setup that blends two shaders decently, but how would I apply it to a circular target?

Tags: materials, shaders, shader-nodes

[image]

This node setup works well on the static box indicated by the blue lines, but upon the circle and the knee, it is not effective.

What would I do to apply this shader mix to a circular target, indicated by the red lines?

[image]

(A person asked for the rest of the nodes)

Comment: Have you checked your UV Mapping to make sure that isn't the problem?

Comment: Nothing here is UV mapped(Both the Box and the Cylinder are default Shift+A items). 
I am avoiding UV mapping.

Comment: Could you share your full nodes setup (not just an image of part of it)? It's difficult to test that suggested alternatives will work as you want without being able to fully replicate it

Comment: Added an image with the rest of the nodes!

Answer (score 7):

<sup>Using the answer from your previous question: [When Mixing Shaders, how to get an organic transition?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/248129/78972)</sup>

You can get there using the *Gradient > Spherical* node.
Again, use a mapping node and colorramp to control the final look.

[image]

You can place it using an empty.
But at some point it gets easier to use UV mapping instead :))

[image]

Comment: Is there a better way to track the area of effect?
I find it incredibly difficult to track it in 3d space across different objects and surfaces, or across different areas of the same surface(like the human body)

Comment: Sure, you can position it using empties. But at one point it gets easier to just use UV mapping and paint the texture directly :))

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use vertex color (or even texture) for that?

[image]

You can get nice transitions using blur:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

[image]

Partial answer, I used a Voronoi Texture node to make round splots of your effect.  But how you'd proceduraly get just one splot, and position it where you want it, I haven't been able to figure out.