# How to blender two materials on the same object together

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

Hey so im working with multiple materials on the same mesh. The materials have normals that don't really line up. (I'm using some textures I got from a CC3 export, and the normals don't seamlessly align.
I want to try to get some kind of gradient to blend the materials together so it looks more seamless.
[image]

If anyone can help that would be great

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can blend any two textures using a gradient.
And also [distort the transition using a Noise texture](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/248129/78972)

I'd use this basic setup to blend Normal maps.

[image]